# MS Access 2010 Rich Text Form Control - Ribbon Not Enabled

Tags: formatting, ms-access-2010, richtextbox

I have an Access 2010 application, with SQL tables linked in. One table has a field for "details". It is NVARCHAR(MAX). On the Access form, I have the textbox control formatted as Rich Text. When I am on the form, and go into that control, the Text Formatting part of the Home ribbon doesn't become enabled like it should.

I have to type text into the control, select the text and right click. I will get that hover-formatting block, but the formatting buttons on the ribbon will also then work. Why isn't the ribbon getting enabled when I go into the control, automatically?

Has anyone else experienced this?  I did a fair amount of searching and googling, but haven't seen this issue reported by other people, so wasn't sure if I was missing something.

Thanks!